# Efficiently writing functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a predefined function that I want to fire when two different events happen. The below code works fine, but is there a way to combine these to make the code more efficient?

```
$("select[name=some_selector]").blur(function () {
    predefined_function();
 });
$("a#some_link").click(function () {
    predefined_function();
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass function reference only. As they are working on different `event` we can't combine them.

```
$("select[name=some_selector]").blur(predefined_function);
$("a#some_link").click(predefined_function)
```

Answer (score 5):

Pass the reference of your function to both events binding like this:

```
$("select[name=some_selector]").blur(predefined_function);
$("a#some_link").click(predefined_function);
```

This should do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

```
function RaisePredefinedOnEvent(selector, ev) {
    $(selector)[ev](function () {
        predefined_function();
    });
}

RaisePredefinedOnEvent("select[name=some_selector]", "blur");
RaisePredefinedOnEvent("a#some_link", "click");
```

Another alternative (not sure when you'd really need something like this just for wiring up events, but fun to code :-D )

```
function RaisePredefinedOnEvent() {
    for(var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        //Note: No need to wrap in anonymous function:
        $(arguments[i][0])[arguments[i][1]](predefined_function);
    }
}

//Code above is quite ugly, but makes this very small
RaisePredefinedOnEvent(
    { "select[name=some_selector]" : "blur" },
    { "a#some_link" : "click" }
);
```

Comment: Not so easy as other answers, but scalable solution. Nice!